# URL for Wordpress site not working (err: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)

Tags: wordpress, dns, netlify

I have the domain 'alexdollard.xyz' registered with Google domains

I added the custom resource record 'wp' as a type A, and pointed it to my digitalOcean droplet (a Wordpress instance)

[image]

I then added a CNAME record for www, and pointed it at my Netlify-hosted site. (This Netlify site is a gatsby/react site which will query my wordpress instance for blog-post data)

[image]

When I ping the IPv4 address of the wp subdomain in my terminal, I get a response. But when I ping 'wp.alexdollard.xyz', I get unknown host. And when I run it in the browser I get "wp.alexdollard.xyz’s server IP address could not be found."

I've been working with this subdomain for a while now and this issue just started. wp.alexdollard.xyz *was* working until yesterday.

I have already tried renewing my DHCP Lease, flushing my dns cache, and changing my DNS servers to public servers. For context, this issue didn't start until I deployed the site to Netlify, and pointed the google DNS name servers for alexdollard.xyz to the Netlify name servers. But *wp*.alexdollard.xyz should still point to this digitalOcean droplet since it's a subdomain, right?

I'm sorry if this question is sophomoric or dumb, it's possible that I really just don't understand the basics of DNS configuration. Seems like something simple is going on. What is causing this issue with my DNS?

Answer (score 0):

DNS entry seem correct:

```
dig a wp.alexdollard.xyz
;; ANSWER SECTION:
wp.alexdollard.xyz. 3600    IN  A   134.209.73.194
```

it is also resolving globally: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/wp.alexdollard.xyz

I can see two options here:

1. your local DNS is stil propagating or needs to be flushed
2. your droplet is not accepting this domain